# USB 3 stick very slow after creating a bootable usb with Rufus

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media, usb-3, rufus

I created a bootable windows 10 usb with Rufus and when I didn't need windows on the usb anymore I reformated it back to defaults so I can use it as a normal usb like before, but now when copying large files it only gets up to 4-5mb/s. It's not normal right? What can I do?

Comment: If it was a cheap-ish USB thumb drive, it may simply be dying.

Comment: @DanielB It's a Kingston 8Gb USB3 stick bought from a tech shop.